# Is there some way to make HTML textareas "steal" tab key presses, preferably without using JavaScript?

Tags: html, html5, browsers

If I, for example, ask a new question on Superuser, and I start typing in the message body textfield, and I make a newline and then press tab, it does not add an actual tab inside the textarea; instead, it changes the currently focused form field to the "next in line".

Is there some way to force it to behave in such a manner that an actual tab is added, as if the textarea were a text editor rather than a form element on a webpage?

If at all possible, I would like to do this without using JavaScript. Maybe HTML 5 has some nice attribute I can add to the textarea so that it behaves in this way? Just like there is the old PRE element for rendering the text inside it as "preformatted plaintext"?

Comment: This may be a better fit on Stack Overflow. You're also likely more to get a useful answer.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about **web development** which is off-topic at Pro Webmasters. Web development questions may be asked at [so] but be sure to read their [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/help) before posting to ensure your question meets their guidelines. In its current form, this question does *not* meet their guidelines.

Comment: On [so]: [Use tab to indent in textarea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6637341/use-tab-to-indent-in-textarea)